# .NET Project Builds For Everyone But Me

Tags: .net, build

So this is a weird one that none of us are able to figure out.

We have a solution in TFS. Everyone else on my team is able to pull the solution down and build it without any issues. I am using an identical workspace, but when I pull down the code and build the solution, it fails, telling me it can't find a number of references.

When I go to one of the identified issues (e.g. can't find referenced class), Visual Studio recognizes the reference and ctrl+click will take me right to the class the build says it can't find. Plus, if I follow the hard path it gives me in the build output for not being able to find the resource, the resource is exactly where it says it can't find it.

I have blown away the workspace multiple times, and I've tried opening the solution in VS2013 instead of VS2015 like everyone else, and that doesn't work either. I have tried removing the references from the project that's failing and then adding them back in, and that had no effect.

Has anybody seen anything like this before?

Have any ideas of something else I could try?

Comment: Try building each project individually.  Sometimes Visual Studio gets stuck in a weird state.

Comment: And delete all obj and bin folders (in those projects).

Comment: Enable MSBuild diagnostics logging on two machines, yours and one of the others. Then compare the results.

Comment: Building individually, the same project in the solution fails. I went ahead and tried killing the obj and bin folders again, but each time I've wiped out the workspace, I've deleted everything on the file system, so they've been wiped out before with no change. I'll try the diagnostics logging.

Comment: @Belizzle when you build the project are you first cleaning, THEN building?  Sometimes this works... sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Lex Li's advice, running with diagnostic logging on, I found that it was complaining about the targeted framework of a dependency of a primary dependency.

The odd thing to me is that the primary dependency (targeting .NET 3.5) built just fine. The project that was failing targets .NET 4.0 and was failing because of the dependency that built without a problem. This makes absolutely no sense to me.

To solve it though, I manually added a new version of the package it was complaining about, and it began building without any trouble. So I can't say what caused this, but manually dropping a different version of the dependency solved it.

**EDIT:**

The above solved it for a time, but then it stopped working inexplicably. A new member joined our team and had no problems with the build, but when he installed some of the updates VS was telling him to install, the build stopped working. It turns out that having "ASP.NET 5 RC1 Update 1" installed breaks our build, and prior to the new member updating his VS instance, nobody else on the team had the suggested updates installed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any [your solution name].**suo** files in your solution directory? Occasionally the .sln file gets locked and is unable to be updated - meaning that project references and similar settings won't load properly. Try the following:

1. Close VS
2. Delete all .suo files in your solution directory
3. Reopen the solution and attempt to build

This has worked for me in the past when I have inexplicable project reference errors that aren't solved by the normal "delete and re-add" trick. Good luck!